# TYPO3 Backend displaying image too large

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In my TYPO3 7.6.4 when I set up a text & media content element and add a picture it is displayed too large, like its shown in the screenshot

[image]

Is there a possibility to fix that? and how?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you are using *.jpg images?

Comment: yes exactly thats a jpg why?

Comment: I had the same problems, but only with `*.jpg` images. I recommend to use `*.png` files because these images a are smaller than `*.jpg` images and working.

Comment: And then the image is shown in the column?

Comment: yes, `*.png` images should only be visible in the column.

Comment: Isn't there a fix for jpg? For me it would be okay bit there are also other Users which didn't know how to convert jpg to png

Comment: I don't know a fix for `*.jpg` but I have a look the next days.

Comment: @Felix please have a look under install tool > image handling setting for ImageMagick and also you can test image type support or not on your server under install tool > test setup > Scaling images

Comment: Thanks gonna Test this later

Comment: @Felix follow Ghanshyam Gohel's advice and then check that you don't has any special characters in the file name or file path. TYPO3 might support this but ImageMagick don't. As I can see in your screenshot it's not cropped or scaled witch means that ImageMagick isn't working.

Comment: Added two screenshots above. One of the error mesages in test setup and one of the actual config. Where are the IM tools normalle installed? and what are the Im tools? .. I'm Running on a ubuntu system.

Comment: imagemagick works fine no erros while test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the image procession in TYPO3 work, make sure that

- you have installed either GraphicsMagick or Imagemagick on your system
- you put the correct path to the binary in `[GFX][im_path]`. E.g. `/usr/local/bin/`
- you put `gm`or `im6` into `[GFX][im_version_5]` depending on what you are using.
- you set `[GFX][image_processing]` to `1`.

You can change these values in the install tool under "all configuration" in the GFX section.

You should also clear your processed images in the install tool ("Clean up" section) to make sure they are generated with an updated configuration:

[image: Clear processed images in the install tool]

Your image processing tests should look like this:

[image: Successful tests of image processing]

Comment: is all installed now and works fine, but display problem orruces as well

Comment: @Felix you could try to remove the `fileadmin/__processed__/` directory, uncache everything and check again.

Comment: clearing all processed image and all temporary files is also available in the install_tool

Comment: an alternative to setting these values unter "all configuration" is:
"Configuration Presets" -> "Image handling settings". the two top options set a full valid configuration for IM or GM (use if displayed green). the third option displays the current state and can be modified to individualize single values afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Bernd I disabled the thumbnails in backend

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your PHP is configured to not execute binarys on the server, so ImageMagick can't be launched.

Check "System evironment" in the install tool for some errors or check if the php setting `disable_functions` containts `exec`.

Comment: no errors in environment check. disabled is: pcntl_exec

Comment: Have you check your error log of your webserver (apache) or the protocoll of TYPO3 if there are some errors shown?

Answer (score 0):

if IM/GM is working well (install_tools test are ok) and the thumbnails in file list module are computed correct its the preview in the content elements.
Have a look at the preview definition of your content elements: is the HTML and CSS correct to show the image inside the preview area of that contentelement?

Comment: its in the typo3 backend? what should I check?

Comment: how your preview images are generated. as you use fluid_styled_content default elements they are rendered with no special fluid/HTML, so the rendering at all might be faulty. in your question you state the usage of TYPO3 7.6.4 which got replaced meanwhile with 7.6.11. have you also updated ?