# typo3 extremly slow what could be a reason

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I've go a ubuntu 14.04lts vserver with 2 vcores and 4GB ram (only 200MB used)

on this server are running 4 typo3 instances but all are test installations so they don't have lots of visits.

my problem is that they are very very slow.

cpu usage 2%
ram usage 200MB

what could be a reason for a slow typo3 in frontend as well as in backend.

its typo3 7.6.4

thanks

Comment: Hard to guess. You can do a profiling as I described [here](http://st-g.de/2011/12/profiling-typo3-with-xhprof).

Comment: thanks I goona test this. I increased the php-memory size, ...  helped a lot

Comment: @StephenKing can you probably have a look at this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906979/typo3-backend-displaying-image-to-large probably you know a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to increase the php memory for the server!

Comment: What was your php memory size before and to what did you changed it?

Comment: it was at 120MB and Now I gave it 500MB

Comment: Thank you. But note that 500MB is way too much if multiple users visit your website. If your server has 2000 MB RAM and you set PHP Memory to 500 MB then only 4 concurrent processes can run. If you set it to 250MB then 8 and so on...
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/changing-php-memory-limits

Answer (score -1):

TYPO3 is a Complex system. and there are Many Possiblitys why the system could be slow.

here are some suggestions what might be the reason:

- TYPO3 Runs in Development mode: See install tool, Development mode disables a lot of Caches and activates additional Debug output.
- Extension/Plugin disables frontend cache. some badly written Extensions disable the Frontend Cache.
- Database Is Slow by default typo3 uses the MySQL database for storing Caches. if you use are shared database from your hoster you might run into problems.
- you are logged in into the backend. (normaly not a major performance hit) but while logged in into the Backend typo3 By Passe some caches.